# Unable to retrieve the last word from a line, using regex

Tags: java, regex

Can you please help me with the below Java regex problem. I am trying to make 2 regex group, but the last word is not coming properly.

```
String str = "James Gosling was an Engineer";
String p = "^James\\s+(\\w+).*(\\w+)$";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(p);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " - "+m.group(2)) ; 
}
```

I am getting output as :-

```
Gosling - r
```

But I am expecting

```
Gosling - Engineer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `String#matches` with a `.*` turned into `.*?` (quantified with the reluctant variant of the `*` quantifier) so as `(\w+)` at the end could grab as many word chars as it can:

```
String str = "James Gosling was an Engineer";
String p = "James\\s+(\\w+).*?(\\w+)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(p);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
if(m.matches()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " - "+m.group(2)) ; 
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/sWN10v)

Note that `while` is replaced with `if` since the whole input should be matched with `String#matches` and the `^` / `$` anchors are no longer necessary.

Comment: I am still getting same result

Comment: Yes just now I tried, I realized from below @roma-khomyshyn reply that i should have added \\s+ to my pattern to make it work fine

Comment: You are using `while(m.find())`. I am using `if (m.matches())`**. You do not need `.find`, you match the whole string here.

Comment: Sorry Yes it did work .. probably I was still doing it in while loop.. Thanks @Wiktor . Appreciate it !

Answer (score 2):

Updated your regex to this one:

```
^James\s+(\w+).*\s+(\w+)$
```

Comment: It only works if the last word is preceded with at least 1 whitespace. Else, if there is a punctuation, it won't work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I am looking for a whitespace preceding my last work